# jQuery Slick problems

Tags: jquery, slick.js

http://jsfiddle.net/hz8ws063/2/

Use the arrows to navigate the slides.
When you get to number 5, you click again - the top slide changes, but the bottom slide does not.

If you change

```
 infinite: true,
```

On .small-click, this issue goes away, but I don't want the bottom slide to be infinite. Is this a bug? Does anyone have a work-around?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix using the `beforeChange` event by slick:

http://jsfiddle.net/un1md5rs/

Please not that I used slick 1.6 there, you used an old 1.3 version of slick for your example.

Besides that it really looks like it's a bug of slick which you should report at their [github page](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick).

Comment: You are a gentleman Christoph - that fixed my issue! Thank you.